# Replacing and writing the updated value to a nested json file in java

Tags: java, json, fileoutputstream

How can I update a value in a json file and replace the value in the file itself? I have tried it the following way, it replaces the value, but I cannot see the updated value in the json file. Thank you in advance.

```
final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + PATH);
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode tmp = mapper.readTree(in);

    //replacing the value
    ObjectNode.class.cast(tmp).get("url").get(0).get("path").toString().replace(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT,configuration.getApiEndPoint());

    //write to the file
    byte[] contentAsByte = tmp.toString().getBytes();
    final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + PATH);
    out.write(contentAsByte);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();`
```

Answer (score 0):

The .replace() method you are using is the one from String, not from JsonNode.

Use this to change the JsonNode:

```
    // replacing the value
    ObjectNode obj = ObjectNode.class.cast(tmp.get("url").get(0));
    obj.set("path", new TextNode("newValue"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that but it didn't work. I could resolve it by adding the following.

ObjectNode.class.cast(ObjectNode.class.cast(tmp).get("url").get(0).get("path")).put(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT, configuration.getApiEndPoint());